doStandardReverse only for some tables that don't exists in the Model
I am trying to use doStandardReverse using ODI SDK Groovy only for some tables that do not exist in the model.
I found the datastore created, but without attributes.
If I manually reverseengineer a table and then delete it, my script works for that table
Can you please help me?
Thank you very much
Maria
}
def ReverseTable(ModelName, Tablename)
{
try {
   
    txnDef = new DefaultTransactionDefinition()
    tm = odiInstance.getTransactionManager()
    tme = odiInstance.getTransactionalEntityManager()
    txnStatus = tm.getTransaction(txnDef)
    // Nome del modello e DataStore
    String myModel = ModelName
    String myTable = Tablename
    
    // Recupero del modello
    OdiModel srcModel = ((IOdiModelFinder) tme.getFinder(OdiModel.class)).findByCode(myModel)
    if (srcModel == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Il modello " + myModel + " non esiste.")
    }
    println("Modello trovato: " + srcModel.getName())
    
    // Recupero del DataStore
    OdiDataStore targetDatastore = ((IOdiDataStoreFinder) tme.getFinder(OdiDataStore.class)).findByName(myTable, myModel)
    
    if (targetDatastore == null) {
        // Creazione del nuovo DataStore
        println("Il DataStore " + myTable + " non esiste. Creazione in corso...")
        targetDatastore = new OdiDataStore(srcModel, myTable)
        targetDatastore.setDataStoreType(OdiDataStore.DataStoreType.TABLE) // Tipo: TABLE, VIEW, ecc.
        targetDatastore.setDescription("Automatic creation of " + myTable)
        tme.persist(targetDatastore)
        tm.commit(txnStatus)
        
        println("DataStore " + myTable + " creato con successo nel modello " + myModel)
    } else {
        println("Il DataStore " + myTable + " esiste già nel modello " + myModel)
    }
    
    // Reverse Engineering solo sul DataStore selezionato
    println("Avvio del Reverse Engineering...")
      txnStatus = tm.getTransaction(txnDef)
      
    ReverseService rs = new ReverseService()
    OdiDataStoreNameAndType dataStoreNameAndType = new OdiDataStoreNameAndType(
        targetDatastore.getName(),
        targetDatastore.getDataStoreType()
    )
    rs.doStandardReverse(
        odiInstance,
        srcModel.getModelId(),
        ReverseService.DataStoreSelection.SELECTED,
        Collections.singletonList(dataStoreNameAndType)
    )
    println("Reverse Engineering completato per il DataStore: " + myTable)

    // Commit della transazione
    tm.commit(txnStatus)
    println("Transazione completata con successo.")
    
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Rollback in caso di errore
    tm.rollback(txnStatus)
    println("Errore durante l'esecuzione dello script: " + e.getMessage())
    e.printStackTrace()
}

